# Print line modified and the line after using awk

Tags: awk

I want to modify lines in a file using awk and print the new lines with the following line.
My file is like this

```
Name_Name2_ Name3_Name4  
ASHRGSJFSJRGDJRG  
Name5_Name6_Name7_Name8  
ADGTHEGHGTJKLGRTIWRK
```

I want

```
Name-Name2  
ASHRGSJFSJRGDJRG   
Name5-Name6  
ADGTHEGHGTJKLGRTIWRK
```

I have sued awk to modify my file:

```
awk -F'_' {print $1 "-" $2} file > newfile
```

but I don't know how to tell to print also the line just after (ABDJRH)

sure is it possible with awk x=NR+1 NR<=x

thanks

Comment: Please clarify the statement "but I don't know how to tell to print also the line just after (ABDJRH)" once too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"_" '/_/{print $1"-"$2;next} 1'   Input_file
```

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, to be honest from one of your post only I got to know if we could avoid any changing in `$0` so applied that sir :)

Comment: Modifying $0 causes awk to recompile the record so there can be a small performance hit BUT you have to weigh that against performing the same action (`print` in this case) in 2 separate places. Usually avoiding doing the same thing in 2 separate places is more important than the small performance hit. So if you're doing `{$0="foo"; print}` then just do `{print}` but if you're doing `/x/{print "foo";next} {print}` then it makes your code easier to maintain (e.g. if you want to decorate or redirect the output) if you make it `/x/{$0="foo"} {print}` (or `/x/{$0="foo"} 1` in your case).

Comment: @EdMorton, cool got it sir, thanks a TON for your explanation here, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming your structure in sample (no separation in line with "data" letter )

```
awk '$0=$1' Input_file

# or with sed
sed 's/[[:space:]].*//' Input_file
```

Comment: That wouldn't produce the expected output, the OP is removing some `_`s and changing others to `-`.

Comment: damn your are right on, sorry too quick to reply. Sorry for bad answer. I change the sed (modification of awk will not be better than other reply)